# Is that possible to add text below marker in google Map?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, marker

I'm developing an google map based android application. I need to draw the Address text on google map. Please refer the Image.
[image]

I refered [this](http://www.nasc.fr/android/android-using-layout-as-custom-marker-on-google-map-api/) link. But it provides to draw text on marker. I need to show the text below where the marker placed. Is that possible? Kindly help me.

Answer (score 1):

Draw text on google maps is not easy. you need external library look ad this [sample](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/maplabel/examples/maplabel.html) [image]

the library used is (new link ) this https://github.com/googlemaps/js-map-label

Comment: The link is given not found 404.

Comment: @abozaid   .. the link is only change the answer is updated with the new (working) link